Mounting existing /home partition with btrfs when installing arch linux
I would like to know how can I mount an existing /home partition that was formated originally as btrfs, and I'll install arch linux and I wanna to maintain the partition and user folder in my new installation

You can find the file in /dev/ or the UUID with e.g:
lsblk -o NAME,PATH,UUID,FSTYPE

and mount it between step 2 and 3 of the Installation guide with:
mount /dev/?? /mnt/home/

or if you can see the UUID:
mount UUID=?? /mnt/home/

Depending on your btrfs partition you may have to pass some mount options with -o.
